# Number of numbers with an even sum of digits in a certain base

Tags: combinatorics

This question might be somewhat repetitive of previous questions, but I could not find anything quite like it.

Consider an alphabet of $n+1$ letters: $\{0,...,n \}$.  Let $z$ be a number in base $n+1$ such that it has $n$ digits. Let $R_n(z)$ be the sum of these digits. For how many z (for a fixed n) is $R_n(z)$ even? What is the behaviour of $R$ as $n$ increases (noting that for different values of $n$, $R$ will be defined on different $z$'s)?

I was thinking of trying something like the generating function for "lucky tickets numbers", but I am not very familiar with those and got lost rather early.

---

Notation: Let us call $D_n = \{ z \in \mathbb{N}:$ the base-($n+1$) expansion of $z$ has $n$ digits with the first digit $d_1 \not= 0 \}$. Let us call $E_n = \{z \in D_n: R_n(z) \in 2 \mathbb{N} \}$.

I am curious about the (asymptotic) ratio of$\frac{|E_n|}{|D_n|}$ (as $n \rightarrow \infty$).

Comment: Do you mean to have the same number of digits as one less than the alphabet size?  You have used $n$ in both places.

Comment: Sorry, thank you both. I mean for each string to have $n$ characters (the first of which is nonzero) and the characters belonging to $\{0, \dots, n \}$.  So, for example, with n=3, there are: 100, 101, 102, 103, 110, 111, 112, 113, 120, 121, 122, 123, 130, 131, 132, 133, 200, 201, $\dots$


For n = 4, there are: 1000, 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, $\dots$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the restriction that the first digit of $z$ is not $0$, either the first digit (for which there are $n$ choices) or the last digit (for which there are $n+1$ choices) can be chosen equally many ways so as to make the sum even or odd given the other digits. Therefore exactly half of the numbers of a given length (with non-zero start) have an even sum.

Comment: Well done.  I was writing up about the same, but missed that the leading digit takes care of $n$ even.

Comment: Great answer! Like Ross, I was writing an answer using a less slick bijection, but let me offer a tiny clarification to your answer. In order for there to be $n+1$ choices for the last digit, the numbers must be at least $2$ digits long. (Or one must consider $0$ a one-digit number.) So long as the length of the numbers under consideration is at least $2$, your argument is correct.

Comment: Oh, actually, I realized that my question was not everything that I wanted. I am actually looking for something like this: I want to keep the numbers that have worked for smaller n too. Would the sum of the cardinalities of $E_i$'s be equivalent to letting the first digit be 0?

Comment: (I can ask as a separate question, if you think that that is wise)

Comment: That would be equivalent to allowing leading digits to be $0$. However, knowing that for any number with $\geq 2$ digits, excluding leading $0$s, exactly half of them have even sum, and for $1$ digits it is  split evenly for odd $n$ too (and $0$ digits - i.e. a string of $0$ sums to an even number). So if $k$ is the number of numbers with some number of digits or less, then the number of those with even sum is $\lfloor \frac{k}2 \rfloor + 1$.