# Concerning the summation of digits in strings: how many strings have an even such sum?

Tags: combinatorics

This is a continuation of a previous question of mine

Consider an alphabet of $n+1$ letters: $\{0,...,n \}$.  Let $z$ be a number in base $n+1$ such that it has at most $n$ digits (so the initial/first string of digits can be composed of $0$'s). Let $R_n(z)$ be the sum of these digits. For how many z (for a fixed n) is $R_n(z)$ even? What is the behaviour of $R$ as $n$ increases (noting that for different values of $n$, $R$ will be defined on different $z$'s; R_n will take strings that are too short and treat them as if they had sufficiently many $0$'s concatenated to their beginning)?

---

Notation: Let us call $D_n = \{ z \in \mathbb{N}:$ the base-($n+1$) expansion of $z$ has at most $n$ digits $\}$. Let us call $E_n = \{z \in D_n: R_n(z) \in 2 \mathbb{N} \}$.

I am curious about the (asymptotic) ratio of$\frac{|E_n|}{|D_n|}$ (as $n \rightarrow \infty$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your [earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1060045/number-of-numbers-with-an-even-sum-of-digits-in-a-certain-base) the accepted answer shows that for any number of digits greater than $1$ exactly half the numbers have even digit sum.  Among the one digit numbers there may be one more with odd sum if $n$ is odd and you don't include $0$ among the one digit numbers.  Zero padding will not change the digit sum, so if you consider all $n$ digit strings there will be an excess of $0$ or $1$ odd number over evens.  That $1$ gets divided by $D_n$, which is huge, so your ratio has limit $\frac 12$